# Finding Required Data From A Very Large ArrayList Of Objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, data-structures, geolocation

An Arraylist Contains 190,000 Objects Of Structure

```
 {
   srno: 51,
   health_facility_name: "keeraipatti",
   address: "Keeraipatti building",
   street: "keeraipatti",
   landmark: "keeraipatti",
   locality: "keeraipatti",
   pincode: 636903,
   landline_number: "NA",
   latitude: 12.005075,
   longitude: 78.533949,
   altitude: 394.6894,
   facility_type: "SubCentre",
   state_name: "Tamil Nadu",
   district_name: "Dharmapuri",
   taluka_name: "Harur",
   block_name: "Harur"
}
```

I Get The User's Current Location Using HTML Gelocation API and send the lattitude and longitude of the user to an endpoint through JavaScript (window.location.href='......')

```
@GetMapping("/nearHospitals/{lattitude}/{longitude}")
public String nearHospitalsHandler(@PathVariable("lattitude")double lattitude, 
                                   @PathVariable("longitude") double longitude)
{
    //call service method to get List of 20 Hospital Objects closest to the user's 
    //location and put it inside the Modal for the view to render
    //what should be the logic here 
    return "nearHospitalsView";
}
```

Now I have a method that will calculate the distance between the hospital (Object in ArrayList) and the user's current location.

Now How Should i Proceed Further, What's an effieicient way of ifnding the nearest 20 hospitals and returning a list of it.

Comment: Have you already verified that the naive approach is - performance-wise - not sufficient?

Comment: Don't  you use any database for storing data?

Comment: Look into the Dijkstra shortest path algorithm and how it works. It may help you.

Comment: @Turing85 yes, it's taking 2-3 minutes using the regular naive approach

Comment: @Rono I am consuming the Objects from an API endpoint

Comment: @behlHardik Can you show us your approach?  and consuming so much data also takes huge time.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find out the top 'x' nearest hospitals efficiently, I would suggest you to use custom priority queue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).